# How to delete random rows from a kdb table?

Tags: kdb

How can I delete the first 10 rows from a kdb table? I want to delete specifically the first 10 rows returned from:

```
select [10] from mytable
```

I tried to use delete with the i index but the count of rows does not decrease:

```
count mytable
2201784
delete from mytable where i < 10
count mytable
2201784
```

Also the delete statement returns a number of rows to my Q console, not sure what that is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If  you want to delete in-place from the table, you should reference it by name.

```
delete from `mytable where i < 10
```

Alternatively, reassign:

```
mytable:delete from mytable where i<10
```

When you run `delete from mytable where i<10`, it returns the table with the changes applied but does not apply them to `mytable` stored in memory.

http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/faq/#how-do-i-delete-rows-from-a-table

The resources at http://code.kx.com answer many questions regarding day-to-day use of kdb.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `drop` operator `_` on the table, and have 10 as your LHS argument
mytable:10 _mytable

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from mytable where i<10
```

Comment: Are you sure? `count md (2201784i); delete from md where i < 100; count md (2201784i)`. Also the delete statement using the `where i<100` condition returns rows on my q console. It seems to work like a select statement.